# No clear elbow and low Silhouette scores K-Means

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn, k-means

I am implementing the K-Means algorithm to group books based on their title and their description.

I pre-processed the data merging the fields and deleting all the punctuations and some undesirables words. I also applied the Snowball Stemmer. Then I applied the TF-IDF algorithm and got vectors with approximately 15000 components.

When I apply the K-Means algorithm I cannot see a clear elbow and my silhouettes scores are below to 0.03.

What can I do to improve the classification?

Comment: Just to clarify here, how big is the final dataset being clustered? If we have 15K features those are extremely hard to cluster reasonable using $k$-means as in such high-dimensional domain data have "no neighbours" ( [Curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality#Nearest_neighbor_search))

Comment: Until now the dataset contains between 6000 and 9000 rows. 
So, should I use PCA?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea so the dimensionality of the data is reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Such Data is

1. Very high dimensional
2. Very noisy

K-means does not handle such situations very well, and nor does the Elbow method (there won't be a clear elbow) nor silhouette (curse of dimensionality).

You'd better use LDA and similar methods designed for text.

Comment: Do you mean Linear Discriminant Analysis or Latent Dirichlet Allocation?

Comment: The one which is "designed for text", obviously... One very clearly is, and the other very clearly is not.

Comment: @HasQUIT--Anony-Mousse You could have simply informed him/her about the specific LDA to use, rather than coming across as unkind.